# Page not found in CodeIgniter after setting route config

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am encountering a page not found error in CodeIgniter after setting the following route config.

**route.php**

```
$route['admin/signup']='user/signup';
```

**config.php**

```
$config['uri_protocol']='AUTO';

$config['base_url']='';

$config['index_page']='';
```

I am not sure why though.

Comment: can you please give me some more information that what exactly you want do? like you want to display 404 page or like that ? or you want to set routing for the pages.

Comment: Set proper base_url. Read here: [WARNING: You MUST set this value!](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php)

Comment: thank you .Now my code is working

Answer (score 1):

If it is in localhost and you did not rewrite .htaccess, make sure your put index.php before using className/functionName.

For example (Assume your codeigniter files are hosted in htdocs in xampp)

```
http://localhost/index.php/admin/signup
```